# C - Find Numbers with Even Number of Digits

Tags: arrays, c

I am doing a [question](https://leetcode.com/explore/learn/card/fun-with-arrays/521/introduction/3237/) on leetcode.com that says

*Given an array nums of integers, return how many of them contain an even number of digits*
I tried to solve it in C

```
int numDigit(int n);

// returns the amount of odd numbers in the array
int findNumbers(int* nums, int numsSize){
        
        int c = 0;
        
        for(int i = 0; i < numsSize; i++){
                
                if(numDigit(nums[i]) % 2 == 0){
                        c++;
                        i++;
                } 
                else{
                      i++;
                }     
        }
        return(c);
}

//using recursion to find the amount of digits in a number
int numDigit(int n){
        int d = 0;
        
        while (n > 0){
                n = n/10;
                d++; 
                numDigit(n);
        }
        return(d);
}
```

Using this approach, some test cases pass while others fail.
An example of a failed test case is this

```
Input: [555,901,482,1771]
Output: 0
Expected: 1
```

Kindly help me improve my solution to suit all test cases.

Comment: A side note: you don't need to call `numDigit(n);` in the`while` loop. You don't even use the number returned.

Comment: if you want to find the number which has even number of digits, then you have to use ```length``` method for a string

Comment: Side note: you made a mistake in `numDigit` function, it should probably return 1 for input 0, but it returns zero.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're incrementing `i` twice in `findNumbers`. Change to:

```
int findNumbers(int* nums, int numsSize){
        
        int c = 0;
        
        for(int i = 0; i < numsSize; i++){
               
                if(numDigit(nums[i]) % 2 == 0){
                        c++;
                } 
        }

        return c;
}
```

You could have discovered this easily by printing `num[i]` first thing in each iteration.

You also had a big no no. You had the same statement (`i++`) in both branches of the if statement.

And there's also this issue:

```
while (n > 0){
        n = n/10;
        d++; 
        numDigit(n); // Completely pointless statement
}
```

You can remove the recursive call, because it accomplish absolutely nothing. If you want to do this recursively, it would look like this:

```
int numDigits(int n) {
    if(n > 0)
        return 1 + numDigits(n/10);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `numDigits(0)` should return zero?

Comment: @CiaPan OP:s original function does that. I made an equivalent recursive version.

Answer (score 0):

I think a better solution would be dividing by 10..100..1000 and if the result is 0,.. while your are dividing by 10^n where n is and odd number. The digits are odd.

Something like this:

```
int main()
{
    int number=1324; //The input number
    int auxNumber;
    int div=10;
    int divExp=1;
    
    while(1)
    {
        auxNumber=number/div;
        if(auxNumber==0)
        {
            if(divExp%2==0)
            {
                //Number of digits even
            }else
            {
                //Number of digits odd
            }
        }
        divExp++;
        div*=10;
    }
}
```

This function can be called for each number in the array and increment a counter if returns even number for example.

More detailed explanation of how it works:

Let's say you have this array: 132, 58
First, you call this function for the first number: 132
In the function you start dividing it by 10 and the result is 13 (it's an int so you won't have decimals) so there will be another iteration because it's not 0.
This time you divide it by 100 and the result still won't be 0.
At the third iteration you divide it by 1000 and the result is 0. because you are dividing by 10^3 and 3 is and odd number the number of digits in 132 is odd.

Next, you call this function for the next number: 58.
First iteration: 58/10=5
Second iteration: 58/100=0. Because you are dividing by 10^2 and 2 is an even number the number of digits in 58 is even.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your suggestion

Comment: I fail to see how this would be a better way. Firdaus way is both clearer and more versatile. Also, this is not where the actual problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Klutt is right, I was testing your solution with the bug fixed:

```
#include <stdio.h>

//Using recursion to find the amount of digits in a number
int numDigit(int n){
    
    int d = 0;
    
    while (n > 0){
        n = n/10;
        d++; 
        numDigit(n);
    }
    
    return(d);
}

// Returns the amount of odd numbers in the array nums
int findNumbers(int* nums, int numsSize){
        
        int c = 0;
        
        for(int i = 0; i < numsSize; i++){
            if(numDigit(nums[i]) % 2 == 0){
                c++;
            } 
        }
    return(c);
}

int main()
{
    //The test case
    int input [4] = {555, 901, 482, 1771};
    printf("%d", findNumbers(input, 4));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @klutt I had already the code written and tested. When I came back I found your answer. This is the only reason I mentioned you.

Answer (score 0):

For each element `nums[i]` it will go through `numberofDigit` function where it counts the number of digit in the element and return the number of digit which is then assigned to `cnt`.

`res` counts the then number of times `cnt` is even will be given:

```
class Solution {
  static int numberOfDigit(int n) {
    int count = 0;
    while (n > 0) {
      n = n / 10;
      count++;
    }
    return count;  
  }
  public int findNumbers(int[] nums) {
    int res = 0;
            
    for (int i=0;i<nums.length;i++) {
      int cnt = numberOfDigit(nums[i]);
      if (cnt % 2 == 0) {
        res++;
      }
    }
    return res;    
  }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you could EXPLAIN your code for the benefit of other users?

Comment: for each element "nums[i]" it will go through "numberofDigit" function where it counts the number of digit in the element and return the number of digit  which is then assigned to "cnt" if cnt is even then number of times cnt is even will be given by res